# project collection build error logger

Tags: c#, logging, build

I want to know how I can get the errors of the `BuildResult` after building a C# project in runtime.

At the momment I have this:

```
string projectFileName = @"C:\Users\Inspire\Documents\Mono Projects\Library\Library\Library.csproj";
FileLogger fileLogger = new FileLogger();
fileLogger.Parameters = @"logfile=" + @"C:\Users\Inspire\Documents\Mono Projects\Library\Library\log.text";

ProjectCollection projectCollection = new ProjectCollection();
projectCollection.RegisterLogger(fileLogger);

Dictionary<string, string> GlobalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();       
GlobalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Debug");       
GlobalProperty.Add("Platform", "x86");

BuildRequestData buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(projectFileName, GlobalProperty, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);
BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(new BuildParameters(projectCollection), buildRequest);
projectCollection.UnregisterAllLoggers();
Console.WriteLine(buildResult.OverallResult.ToString());

                    /* TODO: handle errors */
```

I want to know the errors so I can handle them after the build (here is the comment section "handle errors"), I've added a `FileLogger` file as you can see but the file is always empty (with errors or not).

Thanks

Comment: Check for Verbosity. Try use this - new FileLogger() { Parameters = @"logfile=d:\somelog.txt", Verbosity = LoggerVerbosity.Detailed})

Answer (score 6):

A bit late on this one, but for anyone else trying to do this, I had the same issue. For some reason, when you register a logger with the ProjectCollection, it isn't passed into the BuildParamters object through the constructor - upon inspection, new BuildParameters(pc).loggers is null. It feels like a hack, but I just manually set the logger collection on the BuildParameter object like so:

```
FileLogger fl = new FileLogger() { Parameters = @"logfile=somepath" };

Dictionary<string, string> GlobalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
GlobalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Debug");
GlobalProperty.Add("Platform", "x86");

BuildRequestData BuildRequest = new BuildRequestData(slnPath, GlobalProperty, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);

BuildParameters bp = new BuildParameters();
bp.Loggers = new List<Microsoft.Build.Framework.ILogger> { fl }.AsEnumerable();

BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(bp, BuildRequest);
```

Be sure to not call pc.RegisterLogger if you use this method or you'll get an error about multiple processes trying to access the log file.